# BigQuery UNNEST and JOIN the result from a remote function search function using user query from datastudio

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I am trying to implement a custom text search in lookerstudio (formerly datastudio) dashboard using a custom SQL query as the datasource and a paramater which will be a sentence to search on.

The sentence will be passed to a BQ remote function and the cloud function will return matching results.

So far I have mocked the cloud function to return a string of matching IDs as the BQ remote function expects the result length to match the call length.

```
'{"replies":["ID1,ID2,ID3"]}'
```

I have tried the following to get the results back initially:

```
#standardSQL
WITH query AS(SELECT "test sentence query" AS user_query)
SELECT
    S.Description,
    SPLIT(`data`.search_function(user_query)) as ID
FROM query
LEFT JOIN `data.record_info` AS S
ON ID = S.ID
```

The SPLIT IDs are coming out into 1 row ID (when I run the query without the left join). In addition I can't seem to get it unnested and the description column pulled in, I get the error:

```
Expecting 14552 results but got back 1
```

Is this method of search in datastudio going to be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this here in case anyone else needs a solution to this problem

```
WITH Query AS(SELECT "test sentence query" AS user_query)
  SELECT
    S.Description,
    ID
  FROM 
      Query,
      UNNEST(SPLIT(`data`.search_function(user_query))) as ID 
  LEFT JOIN `data.record_info` AS S 
  ON ID = S.ID
```

The main difference here is the need for the inclusion of the UNNEST function since SPLIT won't separate the input into multiple rows, even if it appears to do so.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).